# extjs nested json store rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, extjs, jsonstore

i am trying to post ext js json store that has some hard coded records..
there is one-to-many relationship between Customer & Product..

```
{
    "customers": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "Ed",
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 50,
                    "prodnm": "xyz",
                     rate:20,
                },
                {
                    "id": 60,
                    "prodnm": "abc",
                     rate:30,
                }                    
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

iam using rails & want to check whether i m getting proper json response..plz help..

Comment: Are you sending the json to the server and want to check it there?  Or the other way around?  Either way I suggest using firefox/firebug if you are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can use this code to get the json from store.

```
function getJsonOfStore(store){
    var datar = new Array();
    var jsonDataEncode = "";
    var records = store.getRange();
    for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        datar.push(records[i].data);
    }
    jsonDataEncode = Ext.util.JSON.encode(datar);
    return jsonDataEncode;
}
```

print that json in console then copy that json and past it [here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/), click on format it will show you a formated json.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check the response is by using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)